# Oracle function to return random date and timestamp between VALUES

Tags: oracle, function, date

I'm having some difficulties creating a function that returns a random DATE( next is a function that returns a random timestamp) when passed in a from and to date range.

I am looking to have the value also include a random time associated with the DATE. For the timestamp function a random fractional value.

Below is what I have so far for the DATE function but I can't seem to get it to compile. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks to all who answer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_date(
  p_from IN DATE,
  p_to   IN DATE
)
  RETURN date DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_start DATE := TRUNC(LEAST(p_from, p_to));
  v_end   DATE := TRUNC(GREATEST(p_from, p_to));
RETURN  p_from
       + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, p_to -  p_from + 1);
END random_date;
/
```

Comment: You're missing a `begin`.  And I struggle to imagine why you would want a function generating a random value to be marked `deterministic`.  That's not syntactically invalid but it doesn't make any logical sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It:

- is missing the `BEGIN` keyword;
- does not want it to be `DETERMINISTIC` (because it will not be):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION random_date(
  p_from IN DATE,
  p_to   IN DATE
) RETURN DATE
IS
  c_from CONSTANT DATE := LEAST(p_from, p_to);
  c_to   CONSTANT DATE := GREATEST(p_from, p_to);
BEGIN
  RETURN c_from + TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * ((c_to - c_from) * 86400 + 1))
                  / 86400;
END random_date;
/
```

And, for `TIMESTAMP`s:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION random_timestamp(
  p_from IN TIMESTAMP,
  p_to   IN TIMESTAMP
) RETURN TIMESTAMP
IS
  c_from CONSTANT TIMESTAMP(9) := LEAST(p_from, p_to);
  c_to   CONSTANT TIMESTAMP(9) := GREATEST(p_from, p_to);
BEGIN
  RETURN c_from + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()
                  * (c_to + INTERVAL '0.000000001' SECOND - c_from);
END random_timestamp;
/
```

*Note: `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()` will return a value greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1 so if you want to include the `p_to` bound in the range then you need to increase the range by the smallest possible increment; hence adding 1 second for dates and 1e-9 seconds for timestamps.*

---

The `RANDOM_TIMESTAMP` function above works but is not truly random as, due to rounding issues, the instant at either end of the range will occur with half the probability of all the other instants between the two extremes. For most cases, this is not a particular issue but if it is (particularly for small ranges of a few microseconds) then you need to convert the duration of the interval to an integer before applying the randomness:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_timestamp(
  p_from IN TIMESTAMP,
  p_to   IN TIMESTAMP
) RETURN TIMESTAMP
IS
  c_from TIMESTAMP(9) := LEAST(p_from, p_to);
  c_to   TIMESTAMP(9) := GREATEST(p_from, p_to);
  c_diff INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(9) := c_to - c_from;
  c_sdiff NUMBER(38,0) := EXTRACT(DAY FROM c_diff) * 86400e6
                       + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM c_diff) * 3600e6
                       + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM c_diff) * 60e6
                       + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM c_diff) *  1e6
                       + 1;
BEGIN
  RETURN c_from + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
                    TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * c_sdiff) / 86400e6,
                    'DAY'
                  );
END random_timestamp;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=80188a7f0af3b6e16544bb1af4996cdf)*

Comment: @MTO made a fix to your solution. See below. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Pugzly Updated to address your issue.

Comment: @MTO I am not questioning your knowledge or expertise as I seen you answered 10s of thousands posts but I believe to ensure you can get data for the last day in the range is by adding 1 day as the minimum amount as I did below. I plugged in your edited change and it didn't work.

Comment: @Pugzly It depends on what your expectations are from the function. A `DATE` always has a date and time component (sometimes the client application you are using to access the database may not chose to display the time component but it is still there) so if you pass in `DATE '2022-04-27'` then what you will actually get is `2022-04-27 00:00:00` and if that is your upper bound for the range then you exclude all the times from `00:00:01` up until `23:59:59`. What you really want to pass in is `TO_DATE('2022-04-27 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` and then you will get the entire day. ...

Comment: ... In that case the query above will work as expected as you are passing the upper bound accurate to the second. If you do just want to pass in `2022-04-27` and get all the times from that day as well then adding 1 like you did is a valid solution for that requirement. So, its not that my code "doesn't work", its that I have different expectations of the requirements than you and I was expecting the `p_to` variable to be the instant when the range stops and not the "day" when the range stops.

Answer (score 0):

I can't generate a date or timestamp for the last day of the range, regardless of where that falls in the month.  For example, random_date (DATE '2022-04-27', DATE '2022-05-03') generates dates on the last day of the month (April 30) but not on May 3.

If p_from is midnight on April 1, 2022 and p_to is midnight on April 30, 2022, then i need to generate a random number between 0 and 30, but (p_to - p_from) = 29, not 30. (Think about it; if p_to was also midnight on April 1, 2022, then (p_to - p_from) would be 0, not 1.) If i want a random DATE that is less than (never equal to ) midnight on May 1, then pass May 1 as the second argument to random_date. To do this automatically, I made the following changes to the functions.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS.FF';

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';


 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_date(
      p_from IN DATE,
      p_to   IN DATE
    ) RETURN DATE
   IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN p_from + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * (p_to - p_from + 1);
   END random_date;
   /

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_timestamp(
      p_from IN TIMESTAMP,
      p_to   IN TIMESTAMP
    ) RETURN TIMESTAMP
   IS
 BEGIN
      RETURN p_from + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * (p_to - p_from + interval '1' day);
   END random_timestamp;
   /


CREATE TABLE t1 (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt   DATE,
   ts TIMESTAMP 
);

 INSERT INTO t1 (dt, ts )
        SELECT
            random_date(DATE '2022-04-01', DATE '2022-04-30'),
            random_timestamp(DATE '2022-04-01', DATE '2022-04-30')
        FROM
            dual CONNECT BY level <= 10000;


select trunc(dt), count(*)
from t1
group by trunc(dt)
Order by trunc(dt);

select trunc(ts), count(*)
from t1
group by trunc(ts)
Order by trunc(ts);
```